# Как сделать якорь на часть страницы django?

Tags: python, html, django

Есть ссылка на контакты (они находятся на главной странице внизу) и мне нужно по нажатию перевести пользователя в указанную часть страницы

```html
<li class="menu__item menu__item_footer">
    <a href="{% url 'main:index' %}" class="menu__link">Контакты</a>
</li>
```

views.py:

```py
class ContactView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'
    form_class = EmailForm
    success_url = 'main/index.html'
    success_message = "Письмо успешно отправлено"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        send_mail('Caparol_Center_Spb',
                  'Теперь вы будете получать лучшие предложения шоу-рума',
                  settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                  [email, ],
                  fail_silently=False,)
        success_message = self.get_success_message(form.cleaned_data)
        if success_message:
            messages.success(self.request, success_message)

        if not Subscriber.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            Subscriber.objects.create(email=email)
        return redirect(reverse('main:index'))
```

Answer (score 1):

кнопка должна выглядеть как-то так

```
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

а список так

```
<div id='contact'>01231456789</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#index.html

```
<div id='contact'>01231456789</div>
```

#content.html

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}#contact" class="menu__link">Контакты</a>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]